# Test works from Dev Console. Fails in automated nightly run

Tags: apex, datetime, dynamic-soql, failing-tests

My query was failing with users with a Locale other than "en_US". So I switched the date format from UTC to GMT and it works well. Unfortunately while my tests work when I run them from Dev Console the nightly automated tests fail. This is the only code that has changed, the queries remain the same. The queryParamToDate and queryParamFromDate are from (lightning:input type="date") components.

Old Code

```
    Datetime queryParamToDateTimeinUTC = DateTime.parse( String.ValueOf( queryParamToDate.month() ) + '/' + String.ValueOf( queryParamToDate.day() ) + '/' + String.ValueOf( queryParamToDate.year() ) + ' 11:59 PM' );
    
    Datetime queryParamFromDateTimeinUTC = DateTime.parse( String.ValueOf( queryParamFromDate.month() ) + '/' + String.ValueOf( queryParamFromDate.day() ) + '/' + String.ValueOf( queryParamFromDate.year() ) + ' 12:00 AM' );
```

New code

```
    Time toTime = Time.newInstance(23, 59, 59, 0);
    Time fromTime = Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Date toD = Date.newInstance(queryParamToDate.year(), queryParamToDate.month(), queryParamToDate.day());
    Date fromD = Date.newInstance(queryParamFromDate.year(),queryParamFromDate.month(), queryParamFromDate.day());
    DateTime to_DT = datetime.newInstanceGMT(toD, toTime);
    DateTime from_DT = datetime.newInstanceGMT(fromD, fromTime);
    Datetime queryParamToDateTimeinUTC = to_DT;
    Datetime queryParamFromDateTimeinUTC = from_DT;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? How are they failing? We need more information in order to help you.

Comment: It's pretty complicated but the test generates users/cases/accounts and then runs the query. We are getting the result 'Bad count of cases returned'. 
`system.runAs(user1) {
        SearchedCases=  customCommunityCaseView.searchCases(null, null,user1.Contact.Account.Name, false, false, false);
      } 

    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals(true, SearchedCases.size()>0,'Bad count of cases returned');`

I am looking into the permissions/settings of the admin account that is running the test classes.

Comment: So it's not returning the correct number of records, and only in some cases?

Comment: Only when run by the automated test.